# How to make sense (handle) when computes logarithm of zero in prior information

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, bayesian

I am working in image classification. I am using an information that called prior probability (in Bayesian rule). It has range in `[0,1].` And it requires computing in logarithm. However, as you know, logarithm of zero number is Inf. 
For example, given an pixel `x` in image `I (size 3 by 3)` with an cost function such as

```
Cost(x)=30+log(prior(x))
```

where prior is an matrix `3 by 3`

```
prior=[  0  0  0.5;
         1  1  0.2;
       0.4  0    0]
I    =[  1  2    3;
         4  5    6;
         7  8    9]
```

I want to compute cost of `x=1` then

```
cost(x=1)=30+log(0)
```

Now, `log(0)` is `Inf`. Then result `cost(x=1)` also `Inf`. Based on my assumption that `prior=0` that mean the given pixel belongs to background, and `prior=1` that mean the given pixel belongs to foreground.

My question is that how to compute `log(prior)` satisfy my assumption.

I am using Matlab to do it. I think that log(0) becomes very small negative value. And I just set it is `-9` as my code

```
%% Handle with log(0)
prior(prior==0.0) = NaN; 
%% Compute log
log_prior=log(prior);
%% Assume that e^-9 very near 0.
log_prior(isnan(log_prior)) = -9;
```

**UPDATE**: To make clearly what I am doing. Let see the Bayesian rule. My task is that how to assign an given pixel x belongs to Background (BG) or Foreground (FG). It will depends on the probability

```
P(x∈BG|x)=P(x|x∈BG)P(x∈BG)/P(x)
```

In which `P(x|x∈BG)` is likelihood function and assume that it is approximated by Gaussian distribution, `P(x∈BG)` is prior term and `P(x)` can be ignore due to it is const

Using Maximum-a-Posteriori (MAP) Estimation we can map the above equation in to log space (to resolve exponential in Gaussian function)

```
Cost(x)=log(P(x∈BG|x))=log(P(x|x∈BG))+log(P(x∈BG))
```

To make simple, let assume `log(P(x|x∈BG))=30`, `log(P(x∈BG))` is `log(prior)` then my cost function can rewritten as

```
Cost(x)=30+log(prior(x))
```

Now problem is that prior is within `[0,1]` then it logarithm is `-Inf`. As the chepner said, we can add eps value as

```
log(prior+eps)
```

However, `log(eps)` is very a lager negative number. It will be affected my cost function (also becomes very large negative number). Then the first term in my cost function `(30)` becomes not necessary.  Based on my assumption that log(x)=1 then the pixel x will be BG and prior(x)=1 will be FG. How to make handle with my log(prior) when I compute my cost function?

Comment: The log of 0 is actually *negative* infinity, because it decreases without bound as x approaches 0.

Comment: Yes. I know. However, When I compute it in Bayesian rule. How to consider that term when prior=0 as my cost function

Comment: Is there some interval `(0, eps]` in which you know the value of `prior(x)` will never fall? That is, if `prior(x)` is non-zero, it will be at least `eps`? If so, pick `log(eps)` as the minimum value that log(prior) can return. Otherwise, I don't see how your given cost function can handle an arbitrarily small input value that won't give you a smaller value than you "chosen" value for `prior(x)==0`.

Comment: In Matlab, `log(0)` returns `-Inf` so use or replace that as you wish.  This question, BTW is not a Matlab question - it's a standard "introduction to programming" question which is solved easily enough either by working with `-Inf` or by adding  `eps` to all your input data before taking the log

Comment: Why do you want to compute the log of a prior?

Comment: @Thank all. I updated my question more clear. Let see my problem to understand what I said and why I take log

Comment: @chepner: your suggestion equivalent my above code log_prior(isnan(log_prior)) = -9;

Comment: @user8430 My point is your choice is heavily dependent on the expected values you'll be taking a log of, or your chosen stand-in for negative infinity won't be guaranteed to be smaller than any of the "real" log values.

Comment: (sorry to whoever upvoted my comment before I completely rewrote it)

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do, before fiddling with Matlab, is to try to understand your problem. Ask yourself "what does it mean for the prior probability to vanish?". The answer is given by Bayes theorem, one form of which is:

```
posterior = likelihood * prior / normalization
```

So places where the prior is nil are, by definition, places where you are certain that your events (the things whose probabilities you are computing) cannot happen, regardless of their apparent likelihood (i.e. "cost"). So they are not interesting for you. You just recognize that and skip them.